# PHP header not redirecting get variables

Tags: php, forms, header

I have a page that takes data entered in a previous page and inputs that data into a database.  It then takes the database id of that post.  I want to use this id ($id) in the header, but when i run the following code, the get variable is empty.

CODE:

```
  <?php header("Location: http://localhost/biology/question.php?q=$id"); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>


</head>
<body>

<?php
include '../connect.php';
    if (isset($_POST['questionSubmit'])){

    $question=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['question']);
    $detail=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['detail']);
    $date=date("d M Y");
    $time=time();
    $user=$_SESSION['id'];
    $put=mysql_query("INSERT INTO questions VALUES ('','$question','$detail','$date','$time','$user','biology','0')");

    $id=mysql_insert_id();

    }
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is mysql_query() doing its job (is it inserting the rows)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not defining `$id` until right at the end.

If you want to use `header()` in your code, put `ob_start()` at the beginning.